# Kubuntu 21.10 -> 22.04 upgrade fails due to missing release file, 404 not found for impish-security Release, etc

Tags: apt, upgrade, kubuntu

I have attempted to upgrade my Kubuntu from 21.10 to 22.04. When I try via the GUI I get this error:

[image]

I have tried to do an update/upgrade using the command line, with an EOL message:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife
```

I next tried following the directions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JammyUpgrades/Kubuntu), but that also resulted in errors:

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
Hit:1 https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com impish InRelease
Hit:2 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease                                                                                     
Ign:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                                                                
Ign:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease                                                                                         
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                                  
Ign:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease                                                                                        
Ign:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease                                                                                      
Err:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release                                                                                           
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release                                                                                                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Get:10 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu impish InRelease [48.9 kB]                                                                                
Err:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release                                                                                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Hit:12 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease                                                                                     
Hit:13 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                                                             
Err:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release                                                                                       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/solaar-unifying/stable/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                             
Hit:16 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                             
Hit:17 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease      
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How can I move forward to upgrade Kubuntu to the next release? I'm not against wiping my machine and starting with a clean install, but I have customized my desktop environment just so and don't want to recreate that. Still, maybe there's a way to preserve this configuration, making a fresh install less painful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked this out by following the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades) -- specifically what seems to have done the trick was to replace the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file with one that uses old impish releases, like so:

```
## EOL upgrade sources.list
# Required
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-security main restricted universe multiverse

# Optional
#deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Once I did that the update/upgrade process went pretty smoothly, and now after a few restarts I'm cooking with gas on 22.04 LTS:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```